# angular click on id should route to different page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

Hi im new to angular and i have json data . SO when i click on Id obtained from json, it should route to different page. How should i do it

Head.html

```
  </head>

<body ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyController">

   <table border="1" style="width:100%">
    <tr >
      <td href=#home>id</td>
      <td>first_name</td>
      <td>dateBirth</td>
      <td>currentCountry</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in list">
      <td><a href="name.html">{{x.id}}</a></td>
      <td>{{x.first_name}}</td>
      <td>{{x.dateBirth}}</td>
      <td>{{x.currentCountry}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>


</body>
```

script.js

```
var app= angular.module("MyApp", []);

app.controller('MyController', function($scope,$http) {
      $http({
        method: "GET",
        url: "http://192.168.1.1:8080/administrator/"
      }).then(function mySucces(response) {
        $scope.list = response.data;
        console.log($scope.list)
      }, function myError(response) {
        $scope.myWelcome = response.statusText;
      });

});
```

my plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/Gpmsc7pb1gfWx3EgKk6s?p=preview

Any help is appreciated

Comment: You cannot click on id. but you can click on DOM element. Secondly you need to use angular route if you want to navigate to different page

Comment: check the answer, i have provided you mock code as well, don't forget to upvote and mark it correct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are **various options** to achieve what you are asking, using`$routeProvider`,`$stateProvider` and `ng-click` or `ui-sref` within that to achieve the **navigation** through **id**. I will go through a simple example using `$stateProvider`.

I will have 3 `views` to mock what you have provided:

- **header.html:**  which contains your `ng-repeat` to show the tabular data and whereby we have the click in the id to navigate.
- **first.html:** if user clicks 1 in the id column, it is navigated to **first.html**
- **second.html:** if user clicks 2 in the id column, it is navigated to **second.html**

**Your JS:**

```
var app = angular.module('nested', ['ui.router']);
app.config(function($stateProvider,$locationProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
  $stateProvider.state('top', {
      url: "",
      templateUrl: "header.html",
      controller: 'MyController'
    })
    .state('first', {
      url: '/app/:id',
      templateUrl: "first.html",
      controller: 'FirstController'
    })
    .state('second', {
      url: '/app/:id',
      templateUrl: "second.html",
      controller: 'SecondController'
    })

});

app.controller('MyController', function($scope,$state) {
  /*//commented this part so that you can work on it later.
         $http({
            method: "GET",
            url: "http://192.168.1.134:8080/administrator/%20ApplicationList.json"
          }).then(function mySucces(response) {
            $scope.list = response.data;
            console.log($scope.list)
          }, function myError(response) {
            $scope.myWelcome = response.statusText;
          });
    */
    $scope.list = [{'id':1,'first_name':'alex','dateBirth':'18th march','currentCountry':'Nepal'},
                   {'id':2,'first_name':'rumba','dateBirth':'18th march','currentCountry':'USA'}
    ]

    $scope.navigate = function(id){
      if(id==1){
        $state.go('first',{id:1});
      }
      else if(id==2){
        $state.go('second',{id:2});
      }
    }


      });


app.controller('FirstController', function($scope,$state) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify($state.params));
  $scope.params = $state.params;
      });

app.controller('SecondController', function($scope,$state) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify($state.params));
  $scope.params = $state.params;
      });
```

In this **PLUNKER** example, i have even provided how you pass `params` through `controller`:
http://plnkr.co/edit/n8p7ycV7k5rsn1f3bQcT?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `ng-click` attribute to your hyperlink tag like this

```
<td><a href="name.html" ng-click='displayFunc(x.id)'>{{x.id}}</a></td>
```

Now you can define this function in controller

```
$scope.displayFunc = function(id)
{
   //Do something with id..
   $location.path('/some route');
}
```

Don't forget to inject `$location` dependency in controller.